# Bold text on google form response email

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I've this script done in google forms to send an email.

I'd like to add bold on "var message" and "message"

```
    function onFormSubmit(e) {

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var message = "Hello, this a new vacation request by an agent "+e.namedValues[headers[7]]+": \n \n";
    var subject = "New Holiday Request";

      for(i=1 ; i < 7; i++) {
      message += headers[i] + ': ' + e.namedValues[headers[i]] + "\n\n";
      }

    var email = e.namedValues[headers[7]] + '@google.com';
    //Logger.log(email);
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

    }
```

*the result is:*

Hello, this a new vacation request by an agent tayzer:

Timestamp: 5/15/2020 17:56:11

Start date (From the, included): 5/15/2020

*the expected is:*

**Hello, this a new vacation request by an agent tayzer:**

**Timestamp:** 5/15/2020 17:56:11

**Start date (From the, included):** 5/15/2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

In this modification, the message including the bold type is sent using `htmlBody`. When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var message = "Hello, this a new vacation request by an agent "+e.namedValues[headers[7]]+": \n \n";
var subject = "New Holiday Request";

  for(i=1 ; i < 7; i++) {
  message += headers[i] + ': ' + e.namedValues[headers[i]] + "\n\n";
  }

var email = e.namedValues[headers[7]] + '@google.com';
//Logger.log(email);
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
```

#### To:

```
var html = "<b>Hello, this a new vacation request by an agent "+e.namedValues[headers[7]]+":</b><br><br>";
var subject = "New Holiday Request";
for(i=1 ; i < 7; i++) {
  html += "<b>" + headers[i] + ':</b> ' + e.namedValues[headers[i]] + "<br><br>";
}
var email = e.namedValues[headers[7]] + '@google.com';
MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject: subject, htmlBody: html});
```

#### Note:

- In this case, when the client can read the HTML mail, the bold type can be seen. When the client cannot read the HTML mail, the text is shown.

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Comment: @Tayzer Damasceno Thank you for replying. If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: No worries @Tanaike, it was what I thought!! thank you